Node.js - AWS X-Ray and Elasticsearch Client, are these compatible?
Is it possible to instrument a node.js application with AWS X-ray SDK simply by using the client wrapper without having to use segments and subsegments?  The app is sort of legacy and it is using @elastic/elasticsearch 5.6.22 (there's nothing I can do to upgrade that at the moment).
For example:

var esClient = AWSXray.captureAWSClient(new elasticsearch.Client({
    host: myhost,
    apiVersion: '5.6',
    requestTimeout: 240000, }):


The problem I'm running into is that the AWSXRay.captureAWSClient function is attempting to call a method ('customizeRequests') on the 'elasticsearch.Client' instance that does not exist.  I'm getting the error:
uncaught Exeption: TypeError: service.customizeRequests is not a function

Seemingly, the elasticsearch.Client is not compatible with the AWSXRay.captureAWSClient mechanism.  However, manually creating segments and subsegments for every single Elasticsearch operation would be a massive chore.  I'm just hoping there's an easier way to accomplish this instrumentation so that I can get distributed tracing.

no. new elasticsearch.Client is not a Client inplemented AWS Client interfaces

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
